# How to CGPath or SKShapeNode Rotation

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, cgpath, skshapenode

I want to add rotated elliptical paths to one center point. Like image below but random rotated elliptical.

[image: atom]

Draw these elliptical orbits with,

```
roadShape = SKShapeNode(ellipseInRect: centeredRect)
roadShape.strokeColor = UIColor.greenColor()
self.parent!.addChild(roadShape)
```

need to make small particles follow those elliptical orbits, thats why I need a path.

```
var followPath = SKAction.followPath(roadShape.path, asOffset: false, orientToPath: true, duration: 10);
particle.runAction(followPath)
```

I used SKShapeNode to draw and get the path property. But unfortunately SKShapeNode doesn't have any origin or anchorPoint property so I couldn't decent rotate to SKShapeNode. Do you have any suggestion to make it rotate or different way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes you're right matt, tried it but apparently something went wrong I'm trying to find the problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18710933/objective-c-how-to-rotate-cgrect this solution explains very well, I'm trying it. 
But still confused why hasn't SKShapeNode  got an anchorPoint or alike.

Comment: matt thanks for your criticism, I've edited question thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let roadShape1 = SKShapeNode(ellipseInRect: CGRectMake(-100, -25, 200, 50))
roadShape1.strokeColor = UIColor.greenColor()
roadShape1.lineWidth = 3
roadShape1.position = CGPoint(x:frame.midX, y: frame.midY)
addChild(roadShape1)


let roadShape2 = SKShapeNode(ellipseInRect: CGRectMake(-100, -25, 200, 50))
roadShape2.strokeColor = UIColor.greenColor()
roadShape2.lineWidth = 3

let action2 = SKAction.rotateByAngle(CGFloat(M_PI)*0.75, duration:0)
roadShape2.runAction(action2)
roadShape2.position = CGPoint(x:frame.midX, y: frame.midY)
addChild(roadShape2)


let roadShape3 = SKShapeNode(ellipseInRect: CGRectMake(-100, -25, 200, 50))
roadShape3.strokeColor = UIColor.greenColor()
roadShape3.lineWidth = 3

let action3 = SKAction.rotateByAngle(CGFloat(M_PI)*0.25, duration:0)
roadShape3.runAction(action3)
roadShape3.position = CGPoint(x:frame.midX, y: frame.midY)
addChild(roadShape3)
```

You can also use applyTransform to apply the rotation to the bezierPath
instead of the SKShapeNode as follow:

```
let roadPath1 = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRect(x: -100, y: -25, width: 200, height: 50))
let roadPath2 = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRect(x: -100, y: -25, width: 200, height: 50))
roadPath2.applyTransform(CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(45.0 * CGFloat(M_PI) / 180))
let roadPath3 = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRect(x: -100, y: -25, width: 200, height: 50))
roadPath3.applyTransform(CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(135.0 * CGFloat(M_PI) / 180))

let roadShape1 = SKShapeNode(ellipseInRect: CGRectMake(-100, -25, 200, 50))
roadShape1.path = roadPath1.CGPath
roadPath1.stroke()
roadShape1.lineWidth = 3
roadShape1.position = CGPoint(x:frame.midX, y: frame.midY)
addChild(roadShape1)

let roadShape2 = SKShapeNode(ellipseInRect: CGRectMake(-100, -25, 200, 50))
roadShape2.path = roadPath2.CGPath
roadPath2.stroke()
roadShape2.lineWidth = 3
roadShape2.position = CGPoint(x:frame.midX, y: frame.midY)
addChild(roadShape2)

let roadShape3 = SKShapeNode(ellipseInRect: CGRectMake(-100, -25, 200, 50))
roadShape3.path = roadPath3.CGPath
roadPath3.stroke()
roadShape3.lineWidth = 3
roadShape3.position = CGPoint(x:frame.midX, y: frame.midY)
addChild(roadShape3)
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer Leo but unfortunately SKShapeNode.path property doesn't change when I run SKAction to node. I need rotated elliptical path to make items follow them.

Comment: Hey Leo you're edit solved to problem with using bezierpath and skshapenode together instead of using SKShapeNode.path property, thanks.